# Is Kohana 3 has something like app controller?

Tags: kohana-3

im kind a new in kohana 3, i use to work in cakephp they have **app_controller** to init global setting controller for all controller. so i wonder kohaba has something like this or not

now i just use dispatch to call it in each controller. i try to find it
but what is the right way to do so ?

thank's for any comment =)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean `Kohana_Controller` class? Its a parent of all Kohana controllers. Also there is a `Kohana_Controller_Template` with a default template operations.

But Ko3 usually uses `index.php`, `APPPATH/bootstrap.php` and `config/` folder for  configuration purposes. Take a look [here](http://kohanaframework.org/guide/using.configuration).

Comment: thank's biakaveron, now i extend class from template controller

Comment: to contain main function example init_controller and others

Answer (score 0):

thank's biakaveron, now i extend class from template controller
to contain main function example init_controller and others controller will extend from init_controller like "class pages_controller extend init_controller"

Answer (score 0):

I like to create a Controller_App that extends Controller_Template, and every controller extends from it. In it I always have before() and after() methods with, generally, Auth logic in the before() and automagically template rendering in the after() (renders a view based on Request's controller and action). Rarely also I put some app-wide actions in it.